# graphical visualisation of twitter data

Tags: java, api, twitter

what method can I use to get locations from tweet messages on twitter

Comment: The profiles have a "location" you could try to use. If you want to know the location based on the IP used for sending, you would need at least access to twitter's log files, but better to the log files of the ISPs.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://blog.xebia.com/2011/02/07/use-data-it-is-easy

Answer (score 1):

All of the Twitter API calls that return Tweets return the Geo lat and long as part of the tweet's data. But only a tiny percentage of tweets contain this data, because people don't turn on the option to have their cell phone add this data. Most sets of tweets I have collected had a geo code rate of about 0.5% or less. Every tweet delivered by the API also the user's complete profile, which includes whatever they have typed into the location field. This is usually some ironic joke, such as "here".